# Why do I need a view engine (jade/pug) just to use res.json();

Tags: node.js, pug

On my server all controllers get data from MongoDB and sends it back to angular as JSON format using `res.json(result);`

Do I need pug or jade etc.. just to send a json result?

If I dont have jade, I get this error:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
```

And if I install jade, then I get this error:

```
Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "G:\Dropbox\ThaiHome\Github\server\views"
```

(I do not have a \views\ folder on the server, do I need to create that to send json?)

Is there a basic simple way to do setup my nodejs server to just parse json to angular?

(I already tried the following with no luck)

```
// view engine setup

// app.use(express.static(__dirname + ''));
// app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
// app.set('view engine', 'html');
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// app.set('view engine', 'html');
// app.set('view engine', 'json');
```

Here is the app.js file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ajp2p0qor74z6o/app.js?dl=0

And here is my folder structure

[image]

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any view engine if you are only rendering HTML and if you dont have `res.render` in you `server` anywhere.

Just use the static middleware instead of any view engine.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

i am hoping all the static html files are in the `public` folder.

**Note :** if you are using this, you must not have `res.render` anywhere in your code. As, `res.render` requires a view engine,it will throw an error saying **no default engine was specified**, if you dont have one.

**Dont' forget to check your `app.js` as well**. As by default express app error handlers use `res.render` to render errors.

Comment: I have no static HTML files to serve from my node controllers. All they do is serve JSON data to the caller (angular).  BUT!! For some reason it wants... something or it will not allow me to throw error or have errors. With your solution I get `No default engine was specified and no extension was provided` and if I put `app.set('view engine', 'html')` I get ` Cannot find module 'html'` all I want is a nice error message in the console in case I get an error or throw an error.

Comment: Ravi is there a way to do this, or will I have to install jade/pug or ejs or consolidate and mustache etc....  Or do I have to create a html file in public to show the error or?

Comment: can you show your project directory structure. also, try to keep all the html files in public folder and see if it works. also, can you show your `app.js`? And, yes! you can do it without any view engine.

Comment: Cool Ravi - let me update the question, give me a few mins.

Comment: ok I put the app.js for you - if you search for "ravi" you can see exactly where my problem is.

Comment: you dont need to do use this line `app.set('view engine', 'html');` And put your html files which you want to show, in `public` folder(you might need to create this in the root of your folder) . BTW, how are you telling your webapp to show a particular file when `/` route is called (i.e. when you app is opened)

Comment: Ravi like this:  `router.get('/getFrontpage', function(req, res) {
 frontpageController.getFrontpage(req, function(result) {
  res.json(result);
 });
});`

Comment: so angular calls `link/getFrontpage` and gets a nice json result back with data.

Comment: Everything works, except when I make an error, thats when the terminal gets angry and yell this at me: https://db.tt/9v2h9CMIgO

Comment: Can you open the chat window again? - for some reason the section where I write was missing

Comment: Ok, yeah this error is totally justified, see your `app.js`, `res.render` is used for error handling, since you dont have any view-engine, you cant use `res.render`. Search for development error handler and production error handler in your app.js, look the code below that. you will see `res.render` is used. you can't `res.render` there, you should use the same method you are using everywhere else and use `res.json`.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard what was the problem with the chat window?? I couldn't see it that time.

Comment: No idea with the chat window - I came in and could see you, but had no chat field :)  - Perhaps stackoverflow had a "view port error" hehehe :-D

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your app isn't trying to render some jade.
Like for example in your app.js file:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        user: {},
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
```

The res.render will try to render an error.jade file in the views folder.

Comment: I checked everywhere - I dont use res.render anywhere.  The only thing I use is res.json.  Is that part of jade too?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard the error is caused by an [error handler](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). Perhaps you're using a middleware that should be handling errors, and which depends on templates?